# How do I define a custom directive using composition API in Vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-directives

The documentation is quite clear on how to create a custom directive using `app.directive()` the "old way", but that does not take into account the composition API way of doing things.

What I expect is something like:

1. `import MyDirective from "@/directives/MyDirective.vue"` inside a component.
2. Use the directive in the component's template like `<div my-directive></div>`.

Preferably without having to add boilerplate like registering the directive in main.ts or anything of the sort.

However, I can't find any clear example or docs page describing this. Is this at all possible? How should I do it? Please include an example of the directive's definition itself.

Comment: It's supposed to be imported and added to component options. Same as components. What you possibly looking for is script setup syntax, https://github.com/vuejs/rfcs/blob/master/active-rfcs/0040-script-setup.md#using-directives .

Comment: @theberzi I wouldn't call `app.directive()` "the old way". It's how directives are *registered globally*. It seems you prefer *local registration*, which would require the [`directives` option](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-assets.html#directives), even if using `setup()`. Note that the Composition API does not support everything from the Options API. The only other way to locally register a directive is to use the `<script setup>` syntax, as EstusFlask pointed out.

Comment: I forgot to mention it but I *do* use script setup syntax. It's encouraging to know I can import directives just as I expected, but how should I define them? Could you post an answer with an example of a directive file imported the script setup way? In other words, in the linked example `import { directive as vClickOutside } from 'v-click-outside'`, how would the `v-click-outside` file look like?